# Drop empty combinations with "by" in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with more than two columns.

```
d <- data.frame(
    a=c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
    b=c(T, T, T, F), 
    c=c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
    d=c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)
```

I want to do group the rows of "d" by the columns "a", and "b", then perform an operation on the columns "c" and "d". When I use `by`, however, I get empty entries corresponding to combinations which do not appear in "d".

```
by(d, list(d$a, d$b), nrow)

# : 1
# : FALSE
# [1] NA
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : 2
# : FALSE
# [1] 1
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : 1
# : TRUE
# [1] 2
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : 2
# : TRUE
# [1] 1
```

What I want is the result without the empty cell corresponding to a=1 and b=FALSE:

```
# : 2
# : FALSE
# [1] 1
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : 1
# : TRUE
# [1] 2
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : 2
# : TRUE
# [1] 1
```

In this example, I'm just using `nrow`, but in reality I need both "c" and "d" for the function, so I really need `by` and not `tapply` (although if anyone knows how to do this with `tapply`, that's welcome too). I'd prefer not to just filter the `by` object after the fact, since my data is very large.

Comment: If you're willing to use `dplyr` you can easily do something like: `d %>% group_by(a, b) %>% mutate(newcol=paste0(c, d))`. If you _need_ a `by` answer, that's doable, too.

Comment: What exactly do you want for the result? I don't really understand your explanation

Comment: taking a blind stab here `Filter(Negate(is.na), by(d, list(d$a, d$b), nrow))`

Comment: Edited to clarify. @hbrmstr Looks good, I'll try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `interaction` with `drop=TRUE`:

```
by(d, list(group=interaction(d$a,d$b,drop=TRUE)), nrow)

#group: 2.FALSE
#[1] 1
#------------------------------------------------------ 
#group: 1.TRUE
#[1] 2
#------------------------------------------------------- 
#group: 2.TRUE
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This gives a data frame with one row per cell except for the NA cell.  `bb` is the result of `by`:

```
> na.omit(as.data.frame.table(bb))
  a     b Freq
2 2 FALSE    1
3 1  TRUE    2
4 2  TRUE    1
```

Whether this will work for other functions depends on what they return.

In a comment the poster clarified that they did not want to reduce the result of `by` but replace the `by`.  In that case try `aggregate`:

```
ix <- 1:nrow(d)
aggregate(ix ~ a+b, d, function(ix) nrow(d[ix, ]))
```

giving:

```
  a     b ix
1 2 FALSE  1
2 1  TRUE  2
3 2  TRUE  1
```

In this particular case we could have used `length` in place of the function but we show it in this form as it depends on `d[ix, ]` and so could be arbitrarily complex and could depend on any or all of the columns.

Comment: It works, but I'd rather not have to create the huge ``by`` object in the first place. My data is huge.

Comment: You could try `aggregate`.  See addition to answer.

Comment: As I said in the question, I need both the columns "c" and "d" for the function I'm trying to use. ``aggregate`` won't let you call a function on multiple columns of the data frame AFAIK.

Comment: The answer does provide for that since the anonymous function depends on `d[ix, ]` and may be arbitrarily complex depending on any of the columns of `d`.

Comment: That's really quite ingenious. I never would have thought of using the `1:nrow` indexing to do that in `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data.table` for big datasets

```
 library(data.table)
  setDT(d)[, .N, by=list(a,b)]
  #   a     b N
  #1: 1  TRUE 2
  #2: 2  TRUE 1
  #3: 2 FALSE 1
```

Or

```
  setorder(setDT(d), a,b) #would be faster
  d[, .N, by=list(a,b)]
  #   a     b N
  #1: 1  TRUE 2
  #2: 2 FALSE 1
  #3: 2  TRUE 1
```